# Check if an element in a row is CSV is with no value python

Tags: python, csv

If I print a row in a CSV I get this result:

```
,,,,,,,some text,1781786000,
```

How can I check if an element row[2] has value?Is this correct if I check if element row[2] is empty:

```
if row[2] =! '':
    print row[2]
```

or

```
  if row[2] =! None:
        print row[2]
```

How can I check if any of elements for row[0] till row[5] have no value so they are just ,, ?

let's suppose that in row[0:6] there's only one element that has a value others are empty, how can I make a condition that checks which element from row[0:6] has value?

Comment: change `or to and` `if row[2] =! '' and row[2] != None:` since both condition are `falsy values` you could do `if row[2]`

Comment: Actually i want to know which condition should i use? @ Vignesh Kalai

Comment: Can't you just use `if row[2]`

Comment: `=!` is a SyntaxError.  Use a loop to check all columns, or use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) function.

Answer (score 5):

The "Pythonic" way of doing this is to simply say:

```
if row[2]:
    print row[2]
```

This works because both `None` and `''` would be interpreted as False-y values and the condition for the `if` would not be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if any element in the row have some value you can do

```
if any(row[0:6])
```

to know witch one you can do a filter and combined it with a enumerate to know its position like this

```
for i, value in filter(lambda pair: pair[1],enumerate(row[0:6])):
    do something...
```

that is functional style of writhing this

```
for i,value in enumerate(row[0:6]):
    if value:
        do something ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
with open('csv_file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if not row[2]:
            continue  # this will skip to the next for loop iteration
        # do your processing here
```